# Database Array Exploding

Tags: php

[I have this row in a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptz6l.png)

and I want to be able to change the values in each block (e.g. [`license_civ_driver`,1]) through a page on a website. The full cell in the database can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/XPyHsTWL).

```
"[[`license_civ_driver`,1],[`license_civ_boat`,0],[`license_civ_pilot`,1],[`license_civ_advpilot`,1],[`license_civ_trucking`,1],[`license_civ_gun`,1],[`license_civ_hunting`,0],[`license_civ_dive`,0],[`license_civ_home`,0],[`license_civ_platinum`,1],[`license_civ_oil`,1],[`license_civ_diamond`,0],[`license_civ_salt`,0],[`license_civ_sand`,0],[`license_civ_iron`,0],[`license_civ_copper`,1],[`license_civ_cement`,0],[`license_civ_rubber`,0],[`license_civ_meth`,0],[`license_civ_cocaine`,0],[`license_civ_heroin`,0],[`license_civ_marijuana`,0],[`license_civ_rebel`,0],[`license_civ_advrebel`,0]]"
```

(I already have all the database connections set up, I just need the query and PhP code to do as I mention).

I also want to make each block translate into text (e.g. license_civ_driver will be Driver License).

As well as that, I want to display each block as a div and have the background change colour based on the number within the block.

I know this is probably a huge ask but I have tried everything to my knowledge including using sites to help me do it myself ([this is my attempt](https://pastebin.com/aUrUj2Jw)). If anyone can help me do it then I would be extremely grateful. If someone wants to make it for me then I would greatly appreciate that but obviously I want to learn so I'd rather be helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: __`I just need the query and PhP code to do as I mention).`__-> no we can't do that.You have to write your own and then return back if any issue arise.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, it's here to help when your code goes wrong

Comment: `but I have tried everything to my knowledge` - but you have not shown any attempts at this

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs hence why I am asking for help

Comment: @RamRaider https://pastebin.com/aUrUj2Jw

Comment: @JoshLisher then where is your code in the post?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs It wasn't included in the post. If you read my last comment you will see my code.

Comment: @JoshLisher and that's why you've had us comment - code should be in the post - not in a commented link

Comment: your php code is potentially vulnerable to sql injection due to the direct use of user supplied querystring data. despite the inclusion of the PHP code and links to screenshots it is not clear which field in the db table contains this data nor any indication why the data is in such a format within the table to begin with. There must be a better way to structure your data?

Comment: its the column which the screenshots show. the name of the field is civ_licenses. at this point in time, sql injection isnt a problem, ill sort that later down the line

Comment: The first thing you should do, is identify & find the person who stuffed data into the database in such a shitty format to begin with, so that you can slap them appropriately :-) … But if you remove the outer `"` and then replace the `\`` with `"` you should be able to parse this as JSON, that should make working with & manipulating parts of it a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice in your code that you are including many files inside a loop - some inside other loops... this is `NOT` the way to do it I would say. Also I believe it is something of a mistake to say `"I'll sort that ( sql injection ) out later"` considering `"...obviously I want to learn so I'd rather be helped."`
It would be better to adopt the good practises early, do it right and then not have to go back.

That said perhaps the following might be of use based upon the comments in the question rather than in-depth studying of the php.

---

**update:**
After reading your comment I added some hastily written javascript code ( and made a minor change to the php generated html ) - it's not tested mor ethan a simple click but should give the mechanism by which you can accomplish the stated goal. Use the request to trigger some PHP code ( same page or other script... ) - validate parameters/data sent, construct sql prepared statement and execute.

```
/* some rudimentary styles for demo purposes */
echo "
<style>
    .class_low{padding:1rem;width:100%;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25);}
    .class_medium{padding:1rem;width:100%;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.25);}
    .class_high{padding:1rem;width:100%;background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25);}
    .unknown{padding:1rem;width:100%;background:yellow}}
</style>
<script>
    const buildparams=function(p){
        if( p && typeof( p )==='object' ){
            p=Object.keys( p ).map(function( k ){
                return typeof( p[ k ] )=='object' ? buildparams( p[ k ] ) : [ encodeURIComponent( k ), encodeURIComponent( p[ k ] ) ].join('=')
            }).join('&');
        }
        return p;
    };

    const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
        let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload=function(){
            if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
        };
        xhr.onerror=function(e){
            alert(e)
        };
        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.send( buildparams( params ) );
    };

    const evtcallback=function(r){
        alert(r);
    };

    const evtbindclicks=function(div){
        div.addEventListener( 'click', evtclickhandler, false );
    };

    const evtclickhandler=function(e){
        let url=document.location.href;
        let params={ licence:this.innerHTML, value:this.dataset.value };

        ajax.call( this, url, params, evtcallback );
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.class_low, .class_medium, .class_high, .unknown') ).forEach( evtbindclicks );
    },false );

</script>";

/* a lookup object to choose correct style based upon integer value */
$matrix=array(
    0   =>  'class_low',
    1   =>  'class_medium',
    2   =>  'class_high'
);

/* fudge around with the database column data. It would be so much easier if the data were originally json in the db!  */
function makejson( $colval, $arr ){
    $colval=str_replace( array( '"', '`','_' ),array('',"#",' ' ), $colval );
    return json_decode( str_replace( $arr,'', str_replace( '#', '"', $colval ) ) );
}


/* words to replace in data */
$arrchrs=array('civ','license');

/* source data - ie: column data from db */
$colval="[[`license_civ_driver`,1],[`license_civ_boat`,2],[`license_civ_pilot`,15],[`license_civ_advpilot`,0],[`license_civ_trucking`,1],[`license_civ_gun`,1],[`license_civ_hunting`,0],[`license_civ_dive`,0],[`license_civ_home`,0],[`license_civ_platinum`,1],[`license_civ_oil`,1],[`license_civ_diamond`,0],[`license_civ_salt`,0],[`license_civ_sand`,0],[`license_civ_iron`,0],[`license_civ_copper`,1],[`license_civ_cement`,0],[`license_civ_rubber`,0],[`license_civ_meth`,0],[`license_civ_cocaine`,0],[`license_civ_heroin`,0],[`license_civ_marijuana`,0],[`license_civ_rebel`,0],[`license_civ_advrebel`,0]]";

/* attempt to make the above usable */
$json=makejson( $colval, $arrchrs );




/* process the data, create a new div per item and assign class using matrix */
foreach( $json as $arr ){
    $class = isset( $matrix[ $arr[1] ] ) ? $matrix[ $arr[1] ] : 'unknown';
    $name = $arr[0];

    printf( '<div class="%s" data-value="%d">%s Licence</div>', $class, $arr[1], ucwords( $name ) );
}
```

This will yield something like this:
[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could make it so when I press on one of those boxes in which the license name is, it would change the value in the database? so [`license_civ_driver`,1] when I press the driver license it changes to [`license_civ_driver`,0]

Comment: set `click` event handlers to each of these constructed DIV elements using javascript ( ajax ) - send (`ajax`) request to some backend php script using POST and use the callback to update the DOM for the client if appropriate.

Comment: Not going to lie, you may as well be speaking another language. Which bit is this request I am changing?

Comment: I mucked around trying to get my head around what is supposed to be going on - put a paste together which might help https://pastebin.com/dvJdEur6
I'd strongly advise a better data storage than this though in the db but that's just my opinion. good luck

Comment: Once I click the license I want to change with this [link](http://joshlisher.phy.sx/ss/images/Code_2018-10-24_14-56-40.png) it then sets the DB cell to this [link](http://joshlisher.phy.sx/ss/images/mstsc_2018-10-24_14-57-01.png) which is missing "[ from the start and ]" at the end @RamRaider

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. I am busy elsewhere today for the most part but you ought to be able to resolve any outstanding issues given the amount of help already proffered?! '-)

Comment: I appreciate the help and I have been trying to resolve this issue but I can't seem to get it to work properly. When the jquery updates the DB it should look like this   "[[`license_civ_driver`,1]]" but it just updates the DB as this [[`license_civ_driver`,1]] causing the data to not be read properly in the game

Comment: can you echo the sql statement and let me see it - add a pastebin entry perhaps but NOT just a screenshot

Comment: With the code you have provided, echoing the sql statement doesnt get echoed

Comment: you'll need to check the console

Comment: No idea where the date `[25-Oct-2018 14:22:04 UTC]` comes from but if you copy the actual SQL statement completely and execute that in your `mysql` client / gui does it run correctly? You are aware that generally the backtick is used to surround tables,columns, function etc etc in mysql and should not really be part of the data in general??

Comment: I'll use that in the future but I got it to work how I wanted it using this as my query http://joshlisher.phy.sx/ss/images/Code_2018-10-25_16-00-36.png